# VBA Password recovery for 64 bit OS - without external software

Tags: vba, excel

How can I reset password of excel VBA automation which have been forgotten by me?

And also I am working on 64 bit OS. And please make note that I don't have

permissions to download any application such as "hex editor".

Comment: Without HexEditor or external software it would be tough. However, are you using 64bit or 32bit office?

Comment: Are you working with .xls, .xlsb, .xlsx or .xlsm?

Comment: I am using 64bit Office and working on .xlsx